# Multiple instances Tomcat as a Windows Service

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, tomcat7

I have setup multiple instances of Tomcat set up and running with a batch file.  Unfortunately when I logoff Windows the tomcat server stops since the batch file can't keep running. I would like to set these up as Windows services, but I get the following error:

**The Apache service named reported the following error: >>> Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Tomcat/webapps/pilot] does not exist.**

I have the Windows service to execute the following:
C:\app\pilot\bin\tomcat7.exe //RS//TomcatPilot

What am I missing?  How can I get this tomcat service to look at c:\app\pilot instead of the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml there´s a section with the entry 
    `<Context path="/myApp" docBase="dir">`
Using this entry, you could configure to where your Tomcat Instance will load "myApp" from "dir".
You could also configure within the `<Host>` tag, but you will find more documentation avalilable with the Context tag.
Hope this can help you.